# fontforge link upper and lowercase

Tags: fonts, fontforge

I have created new characters that aren't currently in the Unicode standard. I want to link uppercase and lowercase characters so scripts and apps can change the case, eg. all caps. How to do it using Fontforge?

Answer (score 1):

The case relationship between uppercase / lowercase pairs is part of character properties in Unicode, not anything in a font. There's nothing you can do in Fontforge other than create glyphs for characters that have upper/lower mappings in Unicode already.